# On the factorial equations $A! B! =C!$ and $A!B!C! = D!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I was playing around with hypergeometric probabilities when I wound myself calculating the binomial coefficient $\binom{10}{3}$. I used the definition, and calculating in my head, I simplified to this expression before actually calculating anything
$$
\frac {8\cdot9\cdot10}{2\cdot3} = 120
$$
And then it hit me that $8\cdot9\cdot10 = 6!$ and I started thinking about something I feel like calling generalized factorials, which is just the product of a number of successive naturals, like this
$$
a!b = \prod_{n=b}^an = \frac{a!}{(b-1)!},\quad a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \quad a\ge b
$$
so that $a! = a!1$ (the notation was invented just now, and inspired by the $nCr$-notation for binomial coefficients). Now, apart from the trivial examples $(n!)!(n!) = n!$ and $a!1 = a!2 = a!$, when is the generalized factorial a factorial number? When is it the product of two (non-trivial) factorial numbers? As seen above, $10!8$ is both.

Comment: You need to look at [rising factorial and falling factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) and n-permutations for some of the notation used.

Comment: You could restate your question as asking when is a factorial equal to the non-trivial product of two factorials as in $10! = 7! \times 6!$ and when is it the non-trivial product of three factorials as in $10! = 7! \times 5! \times 3!$.

Comment: As for the notation, I was aware of the possibility someone had come up with it before me, it's not like I'm THAT good. And, you are completely right. I could've thought that one more through. It was late at night.

Comment: The notation $a!b$ has a well-established and familiar meaning: namely the product of $a!$ and $b$.

Comment: Similar question was answered at  [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/223781/5712).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See Chris Caldwell, The diophantine equation $A!B!=C!$, J. Recreational Math. 26 (1994) 128-133. $9!=7!3!3!2!$, $10!=7!6!=7!5!3!$, and $16!=14!5!2!$ were the only known non-trivial examples of a factorial as a product of factorials as of the 3rd edition of Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory (Problem B23).

Comment: Funny I should stumble upon half of the known solutions to an unsolved problem. Thanks for the references, though. I'll look them up.

Comment: A newer paper, [Laurent Habsieger, Explicit Bounds For The Diophantine Equation $A!B! = C!$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08370). Has other references in it. Is also in [The Fibonacci Quarterly, Volume 57, 2019, Number 1](https://www.fq.math.ca/57-1.html).

Comment: These are also the only non-trivial solutions given in a [2016 paper by Nair and Shorey](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X15002474) (Journal of Number Theory, Volume 159, February 2016, Pages 307-328). They show that this is the complete list of solutions if Baker's explicit abc conjecture is correct.

Answer (score 12):

Immediately we see that any $n$ that's a power of 2 should work. e.g.

$4! = 3!2!2!$, $8! = 7!2!2!2!$, $16! = 15!2!2!2!2!$

Similarly, by combining whatever small factorials we want, we can take $n!$ and $(n-1)!$ to have that ratio. For instance, suppose we wanted to use $3!5!7! = 3628800$ somewhere; we can then make $3628800! = 3628799!7!5!3!$. You can obviously generate an infinite number of solutions this way.

However, the instances of $n!/(n-1)!$ are probably what Caldwell (see other answer) referred to as "trivial". The non-trivial instances of $n!/(n-k)!$ would be given by

$n(n-1)(n-2) ... (n-k) = A_1!A_2!...A_i!$ which -- in general -- I know no way of tackling the general case, but the case where $i=1$ (that is, $n!=(n-k)!A!$) can be attacked:

$n(n-1)(n-2) ... (n-k) = P(n) = A!$

Which is referred to as a polynomial-factorial diophantine equation. This is still largely open, but has some interesting results proven about it -- namely, that the set of solutions is finite for any polynomial P. An extensive treatment of the matter is given in http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2006-358-04/S0002-9947-05-03780-3/S0002-9947-05-03780-3.pdf

Comment: Very interesting reference, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Consider the general equation $$a_1!a_2!\cdots a_n! = b!.$$
People like Paul Erdős worked on this kind of equations. So, they are rather serious problems. Even for the simplest case where $n=2$, namely the equation $A!B!=C!$, we don't know whether there is any other non-trivial solution other than $10!=7!6!$.

Erdős proved that in the equation $A!B!=C!$ if we assume $1< A \leq B$, then for large enough values of $C$, the difference of $B$ and $C$ does not exceed $5 \log \log n$. It is clear that $5 \log \log n$ grows to infinity as $n$ increases. But in fact, this is a very slowly growing function. 
For instance, the first $n$ for which $5 \log \log n = 50$ has more than $9566$ digits. Caldwell proved (1994) that the only non-trivial solution with $C < 10^6$ is $10!=7!6!$. Florian Luca proved [in this paper](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004107000308) (2007) that considering the [$abc$  hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture), we have $C-B=1$ for large enough $n$. Read also a [remark](https://doi.org/10.1134/S0001434610090038) (2009) on this paper if you're interested.

Suppose that $P(m)$ denotes the largest prime factor of $m$. Erdős also showed in [one](http://bsmath.hu/~p_erdos/1981-21.pdf) of his many papers that the assertion
$$
P(n(n+1)) > 4 \log n
$$
would imply that the general equation $(1)$ has finitely many non-trivial solutions.

The last paragraph is taken from a recent work of Hajdua, Pappa, and Szakács, who prove proved in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2017.10.020) (2018) that writing $k=B-A$ for all non-trivial solutions of the equation $A!B!=C!$ different from $(A, B, C) =(6, 7, 10)$, we have $C<5k$. Further, if $k \leq 10^6$, then the only non-trivial solution is given by $(A, B, C) =(6, 7, 10)$. I presented their paper in our MathSciNet seminar at UBC and you can find the slides [here](https://parvardi.com/download/factorials/).

More references:

1. [Discussion on ArtofProblemSolving](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h467540p2617876)
2. Luca, Florian. "[The Diophantine equation $P (x)= n!$ and a result of M. Overholt.](https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/7833)" Glasnik matematički 37.2 (2002): 269-273.
3. Berend, Daniel, and Jørgen Harmse. "[On polynomial-factorial diophantine equations.](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-05-03780-3)" Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 358.4 (2006): 1741-1779.

Comment: Sir, $3! \cdot5! =6!$ doesn't this qualifies as a non-trivial solution for $A! \cdot B! =C! $ with $C<10^6$ ? Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee There are an infinite number of “trivial” solutions of A! • B! = C! of the form:  

N! • (N!-1)! = (N!)! where N is a positive integer.  

If N=3, we get 3! • 5! = 6!  
If N=4, we get 4! • 23! = 24!  
If N=5, we get 5! • 119! = 120! ...

Comment: [A paper by Nair and Shorey](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X15002474) (Journal of Number Theory, Volume 159, February 2016, Pages 307-328) also shows that if Baker's explicit abc conjecture is correct, then $9!=7!3!3!2!$, $10!=7!6!=7!5!3!$, and $16!=14!5!2!$ are the only non-trivial solutions to one factorial equally the product of several others