# When is the permutation of two integers equal to a factorial?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, factorial

Find solutions for $$^nP_r=s!$$

For $(n,r,s)\in \mathbb{N}$

I could find some trivial solutions

$(6,3,5)~,~(1,1,1)$ etc.

Comment: Please explain why downvoted?

Comment: Please explain the notation $^nP_r$.

Comment: $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112670/on-the-factorial-equations-a-b-c-and-abc-d), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294236/factorial-expressed-in-terms-of-two-other-factorials) and [this](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3400513) threads should help.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni.Thanks, they helped!

Comment: Glad it helped. You may find references too in Richard Guy's book ["Unsolved Problems in Number Theory"](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-0-387-20860-2) (the pdf available at the end at 'Download Sample pages 1' contains the part B23 at page $117$ of the book).