# Factorials and prime factorial factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Is it just a coincidence that 10! = 3! · 5! · 7! and 6! = 3! · 5! or are factorials somehow related to primes in terms of prime factorial factors?

Comment: How about you take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294236/factorial-expressed-in-terms-of-two-other-factorials) question?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look at it.

Comment: It doesn't quite answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: Well, $10! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6 \times 7 \times 8 \times 9 \times 10$. So just $3! \times 5!$ falls short in part because it lacks $7$.