# Four fractions of certain factorials give another factorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $n>0$ and $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k$. I looked at the expressions $\displaystyle\frac{s_n!}{(s_n-n)!}$ and found that the fraction is 
 another factorial for $k=1,2,3,4$, *i.e.* 
$$\frac{1!}{0!}=1=1!\;,\;\frac{3!}{(3-2)!}=6=3!\;,\;\frac{6!}{(6-3)!}=120=5!\;,\;\frac{10!}{(10-4)!}=5040=7!
$$ 
The pattern stops here since $\frac{15!}{(15-5)!}= 360360\neq 9!=362880$ and I tried some more without success.

> What is special about the first four? Are there other examples further out or can it be proven that they don't exist?

Comment: I think it's a coincidence; the four identities don't seem to occur of the same reason.  The first two are trivial, the next one nearly so, because you happen to have $3!=6$.  The $6!7!=10!$ identity is remarkable coincidence but it the only identity of its kind known, and it is strongly suspected that there are no others.  (See [Mathworld "factorial products"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialProducts.html).)

Comment: Also relevant: [On the factorial equations $A! B! =C!$ and $A!B!C! = D!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112670/on-the-factorial-equations-a-b-c-and-abc-d)

Comment: @MJD Do you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: Note
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\\
n
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{2}n\left(n+1\right)\\
n
\end{array}\right)=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}n^{2}+\frac{1}{2}n\right)!}{\left( \frac{1}{2}n^{2} - \frac{1}{2}n\right)!}
$$
Suppose $\exists m$ s.t.
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\\
n
\end{array}\right)=m!.
$$
Then,
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}n^{2}+\frac{1}{2}n\right)!=m!\left(\frac{1}{2}n^{2}-\frac{1}{2}n\right)!
$$
and either $m!$ or $\left(\frac{1}{2}n^{2}-\frac{1}{2}n\right)!$
divide $\left(\frac{1}{2}n^{2}+\frac{1}{2}n\right)!$.

Comment: @jathd Okay, but I'm not sure it really *is* an answer.

Comment: @par interesting...

Comment: @draks...: just expanding on what MJD wrote. also I made a silly mistake: should say both divide $\left(1/2 n^2 + 1/2 n\right)!$, not either or

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a coincidence; the four identities don't seem to occur of the same reason. The first two are trivial, the next one nearly so, because you happen to have $3!=6$. The $6!7!=10!$ identity is remarkable coincidence but it the only identity of its kind known, and it is strongly suspected that there are no others. (See the [Mathworld article on "factorial products"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialProducts.html).)

So I think what you have here is the (well-known and probably unique) coincidence that $6!7! = 10$, and then that happens to line up with three smaller cases that are less surprising.