# Is there a subgroup of $S_{10}$ having $5040$ elements other than $S_7$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials

I'm trying to generate to monomial symmetric polynomial 
$$
m_{(1,2,3,4)}(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{10})=X_1^1X_2^2X_3^3X_4^4 + \text{all permutations,}
$$
starting from the first element by applying all necessary permutations.

Since $m_{(1,2,3,4)}(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{10})$ has $\frac{10!}{6!}=5040$ elements, I think that not all elements of $S_{10}$ are necessary and I wonder if there is a subgroup of it.

I found $S_7$ to have the right number of elements, but first this doesn't make sense to me and second my next example would be $m_{(1,2,3,4,5)}(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{15})$, where $S_9$ doesn't match (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/446904/19341) for a related question).

Comment: What you're looking at is a _subset_ of $S_{10}$, but it's not a sub_group_ in any natural sense.  If you just want all of the relevant ordered combinations of that length, there are better ways of getting there than by walking through the elements of $S_{10}$; searching on 'generating all combinations' should provide useful information.  (Note that once you're iterating over all combinations, getting all ordered combinations is easy.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki ah ok, thanks, I expected something like this. So the answer is: No...?

Comment: well, I freely admit I don't actually know the answer to the posted question as it's stated (are there any other subgroups of $S_{10}$ of that size?)!  I'm just noting that your particular structure is not, in any natural sense that I can see, a group.  But it seems likely that whether it's a group or not is wholly irrelevant to the question of how best to iterate through them.

Comment: The answer to the question that was asked is yes: $A_7 \times C_2$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki do the subsets create a kind of *coset* structure?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki maybe along the lines shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/455187/19341)?

Comment: You seem to have stumbled across the equation $6!7!=10!$, which is nice but rather exceptional.