# Finding natural numbers $a, b, c$ such that $a!=b!\times c!$

Tags: number-theory, factorial

Yesterday, when I was playing with numbers, I was surprised to know the following relation:

$$10!=6!\times 7!.$$

Then, I've been looking for the other solutions, but I'm facing difficulty. Then, here are my questions.

**Question 1** : Does there exist the other non-trivial solution?

**Question 2** : Can we get all solutions? In addition to this, can we prove that they are all solutions?

I don't know if these questions are famous. Also, I'm afraid that these questions might be very easy to solve. Anyway, I need your help.

Comment: See this MSE post and its answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112670/on-the-factorial-equations-a-b-c-and-abc-d

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialProducts.html

Comment: $6! = 3! \, 5!$, $10! = 6! \, 7!$, $24! = 4! \, 23!$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Many thanks.

Comment: @mathlove, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Notice that $7$ is the largest prime $\leq 10$.

Comment: How exactly does this contribute to solving $a!=b!c!$.

Comment: that is one of the reasons for $10\times9\times8\times7$ to be equal to $7!$. We need to search for examples so that $b$ or $c$ is the largest prime lesser than $a$, that somehow narrows down the search.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha: Thank you very much!