# $n!$ as product of consecutive numbers

Tags: factorial

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

In how many ways can one write $n!$ as a product of consecutive integers?

For example: $4!=1\times2\times3\times4=2\times3\times4$. Here, $2$ possibilities exist.

$5!=1\times2\times3\times4\times5=2\times3\times4\times5=4\times5\times6$. Here, $3$ possibilities exist.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Could you try to reformulate your question?

Comment: i know its grammar really bad, but i coldn't write. Can somebody change it?

Comment: example: $4!=1.2.3.4=2.3.4=24$. We can write it 3 ways.

Comment: I think it would be more proper to say that you can write $4!$ **two ways**, one as $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4$, and the other without the one. I suppose that is trivial and therfore all $n!$ can be written as a product of consecutive integers a minimum of two ways, provided $n$ is a positive Integer greater than 1.

Comment: But I do not know of a general procedure for counting the ways above the two trivial ones. For this reason, I'm up voting your question.

Comment: i changed it, thanks.

Comment: In other words, the question is: what is the cardinality of the following set?

$$
A_n = \{(\ell,s)\in\mathbb{N}^2,s>\ell | \prod_{k=\ell}^s k = n!\}
$$

Clearly $(2,n)\in A_n$. As the user showed, for $n=5$, $(4,6)\in A_5$, so the question is non trivial.

Comment: The question says "a product of consecutive integers" but the subject line says "a multiple of consecutive integers".  $720=6!$ is a multiple of the consecutive integers $15$ and $16$ but it is not their product.  (It is also a multiple of $8,9,10$ and it _is_ their product.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @153, it looks like you meant "product" rather than "multiple". Is that right? If so, you should edit the question title.

Comment: $5040=7!$ is a multiple of the consecutive integers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$, but it is not their product.  It is also a multiple of the consecutive integers $14,15,16$ but not their product.  And a multiple of $20,21$ but not their product.  And a multiple of $35,36$ but not their product. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So $1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times6 = 8\times9\times10$ is an example of what is sought. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael, It is just for fun. Today is Friday.

Comment: See the reference in Gerry Myerson's answer at the near-duplicate question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/112709/30402

Comment: $1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times6\times7 = 7\times8\times9\times10$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The products of consecutive integers, $(m+1)\cdot (m+2)\cdot(m+3)\cdots n$ is a factorial from which you have removed the first factors, i.e $\dfrac{n!}{m!}$. To make this equal another factorial, you need to discard the largest factors of $n!$, i.e. $n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdots$.

It is always possible to discard $n$ itself. This yields 
$$\frac{(m!)!}{m!}=(m!-1)!$$
For instance
$$5\cdot6\cdots24=1\cdot2\cdots23.$$
and there are infinitely many solutions, extremely large.
Other solutions are accidental and rare.

Answer (score 3):

There are infinitely many $n$ for which $n!$ can be written in 3 ways. All you have to do is set $n_k = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \ldots \cdot k$. Then whenever $n = n_k - 1$ for some $k$, you can remove the first $k$ numbers in the product and add $n_k$ to the end. It seems much more complicated to prove that you can add, say, two extra consecutive numbers to the end of the product for infinitely many $n$ (and determine for which $n$ when you can, in analytic or fast computational form). If you add two numbers to the end, $n+1$ and $n+2$, then $GCD(n+1,n+2) = 1$ so somehow $n+1$ and $n+2$ must partition the prime factors of $n_k!$. I'm currently running a computer search to find the first $n$ (if any) where this is possible. I'll update if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It exists at least 2 trivial combinations (1*2*...*n and 2*3*...*n).

It will also exist a third combination if n+1 is the potencial of other number, although it is not an enough condition.

For example:

while 23! = 1*2*3*...*23 = 2*3*4*5*...*23 = 5*6*...*23*24

To get a fourth combination continuing this method, it would have to be a number that reach next conditions:

- n+1 = m!
- n+2 = p!/m!

but as soon as p!/m! is always an even number (p>m+1), the difference between it and m! (also even) cannot be one.

For that reason, it is not possible to have 4 combinations.

Comment: But $6!=8\cdot9\cdot10$.

Comment: I had consider that you had to do new combinations in order. Then you should always consider one more combination: 6! = 720

Comment: @Zeropoint The point is that your argument is not a *proof* that it's impossible to have $4$ combinations, because the third/fourth combination might occur in a way that you haven't considered.  You said "You can never substitute a new number in the series unless it respects that rule."

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I understimated the freedom of the exercise.