# Find $a,b,c$ such that $a!\times b!\times c!=d!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

> I have to find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that-$a!\times b!\times c!=d!$

Answer given in my book is $3!\times5!\times7!=10!$(But it is written that other answers are also possible).

What is a systematic way to find the answer without using a calculator or computer?(I mean without brute force calculation)

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: One set of solutions is a,b,c and d are in the set {0,1}.

Comment: related : [On the factorial equations $A! B! =C!$ and $A!B!C! = D!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112670/on-the-factorial-equations-a-b-c-and-abc-d)

Comment: There are many uninteresting answers, such as $12!=11!\cdot 12=11!\cdot 2!\cdot 3!$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Your answer provides one way of approaching the solution....But you are fortunate that 12 can be expressed as a product of two factorials...not all numbers can be expressed as a product of two factorials:-)...

Comment: @tatan The point is we can always take $a=b!c!-1,\,d=b!c!$ for a trivial solution.