# Diophantine equation involving factorials

Tags: diophantine-equations, nested-radicals

$$x!+y=y^3$$
$$y=\sqrt[3]{x!+\sqrt[3]{x!+\sqrt[3]{x!+\cdots}}}$$

The only integer solutions to these identities that I have found are:

$$3!+2=2^3$$
$$4!+3=3^3$$
$$5!+5=5^3$$
$$6!+9=9^3$$

I conjecture these are all the solutions. Is that true

Comment: I think you can rephrase it as: "are $3!,4!,5!,6!$ the only faculties that can be written as a product of $3$ consecutive integers?"

Comment: Brute force agrees up to $x=1000$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112670/on-the-factorial-equations-a-b-c-and-abc-d)

Comment: Since $x!=(y+1)y(y-1)=z(z-1)(z-2)$ (writing $z$ for $y+1$) you could maybe try and show that $\dfrac{z!}{(z-3)!}$ cannot be expressed as the factorial of a single integer for $z>10$.

Comment: For large $x$ it will be incredibly difficult to find a solution since $y^3 - y$ will have to be highly divisible. Consider different valutations mod different primes. 2 is a good place to start.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the ABC conjecture the following paper shows that there should only be finitely many solutions.

https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/37.2/37(2)-04.pdf

I would probably bet that the solutions you have found are all of the solutions.