# Find all numbers whose factorial equals the product of (more than 1) consecutive numbers greater than that number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, factorial, open-problem

This problem is basically equivalent to the nontrivial case of the problem of finding a product of two factorials that is also a factorial, but that problem seems to be open as well. The keyword here is *seems*: I have no idea whether it has any solution yet. Thanks in advance for any help!

Sorry, I meant numbers. I am just extremely, *extremely* sorry.

Comment: We have, for example, $6!=8\times 9 \times 10$.

Comment: consecutive *digits*? so the numbers whose factorial you have to verify are from $1$ to $8$?

Comment: Do you really meant _digits_ in the title? Or numbers?

Comment: I would be very interested in your approaches so far.

Answer (score 0):

The factorial of the number is equal to consecutive *digits*, greater than the number. So $n\leq8$. We have to check those 8 cases

for $n=1$, $n=2$ there aren't solutions

for $n=3$, $3!=6 \leq 4 * 5$

for $n=4$, $4!=24 \leq 5* 6$

for $n\geq5$, the product does to have divisble with 5. The digits are greater than the number, but there aren't any digits greater than 5 divisble with 5.

So, there aren't any solutions.
If you didn't mean digits and you wanted to say numbers, we'll have to look for a different approach.

Comment: Sorry. I meant numbers. I wonder what happens to me sometimes.

Comment: It's okay. But I can't delete my answer. I flaged it, that's all I can do

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution but I think the problem is very interesting. So I state how far i came (note: I am not a number theorist).

At first, the number of occurences of the prime factor $p$ in $n!$ is
$$c_p(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac n{p^i} \right\rfloor.$$
(I can elaborate this, but I think this is not the important part.) This is roughly
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac n{p^i} \right\rfloor
\approx 
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac n{p^i}=\frac{n}{p-1}.
$$
For $n!\times m!=K!$ it must hold $c_p(n)+c_p(m)=c_p(K)$. By the above estimation this gives $n+m\approx K$. I guess one can do much better results by more precise estimations of $c_p(n)$.

---

Assume $K\geq n+m$, espcially $m\leq K-n$. Then we have
$$\frac{K!}{n!\cdot m!} \geq\frac{K!}{n!\cdot(K-n)!}={K\choose n}>1$$
for $n\not=0,K$. So we have $K<m+n$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is to find all numbers $m$ such that there exists $j>k>1$ so that
$$m! = \frac{j!}{k!}$$
For all such cases, the numbers $j$ are listed in [OEIS A109095](https://oeis.org/A109095). Every time $j$ is of the form $j=x!$ for some natural number $x\ge 3$, we have a "trivial" example:
$$(x!)! = x! \cdot (x!-1)!$$
or:
$$(x!-1)! = \frac{(x!)!}{x!}$$
For $x=3$ this gives:
$$5! = 6\cdot 5\cdot 4$$
For $x=4$ gives:
$$23! = 24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot\ldots\cdot 5$$
For $x=5$:
$$119! = 120\cdot 119\cdot 118\cdot\ldots\cdot 6$$
For $x=6$:
$$719! = 720\cdot 719\cdot 718\cdot\ldots\cdot 7$$
$x=7$:
$$5039! = 5040\cdot 5039\cdot 5038 \cdot\ldots\cdot 8$$
And so on.

My source for this is the OEIS entry linked above.

So the question becomes, are there other examples outside this infinite sequence?

OEIS and a comment to the question gives $10! = 6! \cdot 7!$ which holds *two* examples:
$$6! = 10\cdot 9\cdot 8 \text{ and } 7! = 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7$$

So who can find other examples, or prove that no more examples exist?

The examples I mentioned are $m=5,6,7,23,119,719,\ldots$.

I found related threads, see e.g. [On the factorial equations $A! B! =C!$ and $A!B!C! = D!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112670/) and the threads link to it.