# Find all such positive integers $x(>1), y(>1)$ and $z$ so that $x! \cdot y! =z!$ holds.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial

Upon inspection, I found out that: $3!\cdot5! =6! $ and $6!\cdot7! =10!.$ (couldn't dare to search for more such triplets)

How to check whether there exist more such triplets or not? Please show me a proper way to handle such problems.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112670/on-the-factorial-equations-a-b-c-and-abc-d) is relevant, especially answer by Amir Hossein.

Comment: Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Your $3!\cdot 5! =6!$ is an example of the case  for general $n$:

$$n! \cdot (n!-1)! = (n!)!$$

and when $n=4$ this gives $4! \cdot 23! = 24!$

Comment: This suggests that there are infinite number of such triplets. The form $n!\cdot(n! -1)! =(n!)!$ is generated on the basis of $3! ×5! =6!.$ But this form doesn't imply the existence of $6!×7! =10!$. So can't we find a single general form so that $x! \cdot y! =z! $ holds? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can observe that

$$(n!-1)!.(n!)=(n!)!$$

If $ n=3$, it gives

$$5!.3!=6!$$
for $ n=4 $, we get

$$23!.4!=24!$$
and so on.